# LocalStorage possui algum limite de armazenamento?

Tags: html5, localstorage

Eu preciso armazenar uma quantidade muito grande de palavras/frases no navegador do usuário, gostaria de saber se utilizar `localStorage` é uma boa opção. Se sim, há alguma restrição/limite na quantidade de informações que posso armazenar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `localStorage` possui limite sim, e depende do browser as regras.

- No Chrome o limite é de 5MB de dados, por origem.
- O Opera irá perguntar ao usuário se ele permite que o site use mais dados, quando o limite é alcançado.

Essas informações não são especificadas formalmente, e podem mudar com o tempo, assim como quanto às opções de controle por parte do usuário.

**Detectando o tamanho do storage:**

[Neste resposta do SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812530/195417) há um script para detectar o tamanho do storage. Eu fiz umas alterações para ficar mais eficiente:

```
const resolution = 100,
    MIN = 100, // 100KB
    MAX = 30000; // 30MB

if (!localStorage.getItem('localStorage-size'))
{
    var str1024x = new Array(1024+1).join(new Array(resolution+1).join('a'));
    localStorage.removeItem('test');
    var min = MIN / resolution, max = MAX / resolution, lastUsed;
    while (max - min > 1) {
        var i = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
        console.log(i);
        try {
            var str = new Array(i+1).join(str1024x);
            localStorage.setItem('test', str);
            lastUsed = i;
            min = i;
        } catch (e) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    localStorage.removeItem('test');
    localStorage.setItem('localStorage-size', lastUsed * resolution);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/95o0ubto/1/) <sup>(infelizmente não funcionou na ferramenta de script inline aqui do SO-PT, por isso o exemplo está no jsfiddle)</sup>

**Fontes:**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Storage_size
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989317/195417
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812530/195417