# Guardando dados por um tempo

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Existe alguma forma usando o *javascript cookies* que eu possa guardar uma informação por 3 horas por exemplo ?

Em meu cenário preciso ter uma página de avisos, mas não preciso guardar esses registros em banco de dados. Preciso que esses avisos fiquem por pelo menos 3 horas na página depois expire.

Buscando sobre *javascript* achei esse *cookie*. Então, basicamente eu queria que tivesse uma *textarea* com um botão de *submit*, e quando o usuário escrever o aviso e clicasse no botão, o conteúdo da *textarea* aparecesse em uma *div* e ficasse lá por 3 horas.

Mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso e não sei se é viável.

*Lembrando aqui que seriam vários avisos. Ou seja, pode ser que no dia pode ter mais de um aviso, então queria mostrar todos, e de acordo com o tempo eles irem sumindo(expirando) da página.

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar ? Existe alguma outra forma que possa fazer isso, sem precisar criar tabelas e que tenha esse tempo para expirar ?

## EDIT

Eu fiz um código aqui que funciona. Mas queria adaptar ele ao meu cenário. Ou seja, o aviso fica lá por 3 horas e depois expira.

```
<div class="row">
<h3>Digite o aviso</h3>
<form id="frmCadastro">
    <textarea id="aviso" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="btnSalvar" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {

        var operacao = "A"; //"A"=Adição; "E"=Edição

        var indice_selecionado = -1;

        var tbClientes = localStorage.getItem("tbClientes");// Recupera os dados armazenados

        tbClientes = JSON.parse(tbClientes); // Converte string para objeto

        if (tbClientes == null) // Caso não haja conteúdo, iniciamos um vetor vazio
            tbClientes = [];

        function Adicionar() {
            var cliente = JSON.stringify({
                Aviso: $("#aviso").val(),
            });

            tbClientes.push(cliente);

            localStorage.setItem("tbClientes", JSON.stringify(tbClientes));
            return true;
        }

        function Editar() {
            tbClientes[indice_selecionado] = JSON.stringify({
                Aviso: $("#aviso").val(),
            });
            localStorage.setItem("tbClientes", JSON.stringify(tbClientes));
            operacao = "A";
            return true;
        }

        function Listar() {
            $("#tblListar").html("");
            $("#tblListar").html(
                "<thead>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<th>Avisos</th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                "<tbody>" +
                "</tbody>"
                );

            for (var i in tbClientes) {
                var cli = JSON.parse(tbClientes[i]);
                $("#tblListar tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                             "  <td>" + cli.Aviso + "</td>" +
                                             "  <td><img src='Imagens/edit.png' alt='" + i + "' class='btnEditar'/><img src='Imagens/deleta.png' alt='" + i + "' class='btnExcluir'/></td>" +
                                             "</tr>");
            }
        }

        function Excluir() {
            indice_selecionado = parseInt($(this).attr("alt"));
            tbClientes.splice(indice_selecionado, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("tbClientes", JSON.stringify(tbClientes));
            alert("Aviso excluído.");
        }

        function GetCliente(propriedade, valor) {
            var cli = null;
            for (var item in tbClientes) {
                var i = JSON.parse(tbClientes[item]);
                if (i[propriedade] == valor)
                    cli = i;
            }
            return cli;
        }

        Listar();

        $("#frmCadastro").bind("submit", function () {
            if (operacao == "A")
                return Adicionar();
            else
                return Editar();
        });

        $(".btnEditar").bind("click", function () {
            operacao = "E";
            indice_selecionado = parseInt($(this).attr("alt"));
            var cli = JSON.parse(tbClientes[indice_selecionado]);
            $("#aviso").val(cli.Aviso);
            $("#aviso").focus();
        });

        $(".btnExcluir").bind("click", function () {
            indice_selecionado = parseInt($(this).attr("alt"));
            Excluir();
            Listar();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O problema dos cookies é que eles são individuais por cliente, não que você precise de banco de dados mas você vai precisar de alguma logica server side para redistribuir a informação.

Comment: Existe alguma outra forma, além do javascript que eu possa fazer isso ?

Comment: Ué, você pode mandar o aviso para o seu backend que guarda na memória junto com a data e hora que o aviso foi recebido, todas as pessoas solicitando os avisos, pro exemplo em `GET /avisos` só recebem os avisos recentes (e você descarta apropriadamente os avisos antigos). O problema de você não utilizar um BD é que no caso do seu servidor cair você perde as mensagens, e caso de você tenha um cluster você ainda vai precisar implementar uma logica para redistribuir os avisos entre seus servidores.

Comment: Você pode usar [coleções do MongoDb com TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) também! Mas só se voce ja estiver usando o MongoDb, senão seria overkill.

Comment: Eu uso *asp.net mvc* com *sql server express 2012*. Não coloquei na pergunta a *tag* porque não achei que seria necessário. :(

Comment: Se não me engano o .net tem o escopo de application, quem sabe você não guarda lá as mensagens e implementa a lógica de deleção das mensagens mais antigas...

Comment: Então vou adicionar a tag do asp.net mvc. Talvez assim eu consiga uma reposta esclarecedora né ?

Comment: Você pode considerar armazenar essas informações por meio da API `localStorage`, somente com Javascript. "Considerar" pois, como dito por você "seriam vários avisos" e [localStorage possui limite de armazenamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42397/localstorage-possui-algum-limite-de-armazenamento).

Comment: Mas não seria algo tão pesado assim. Seriam poucos avisos. Será que tinha colocar uma resposta com código usando meu cenário ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago e se o utilizador fechar a janela queres que tudo recomece? ou fechando e voltando a abrir queres que as 3 horas sejam contadas?

Comment: Quero que mesmo fechando a janela continue lá,contando as 3 horas. Pra ficar uma coisa mais simplificada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o localStorage para essa finalidade, exemplo:

Pegue o datetime e armazene numa variavel, insirá ela no localstorage.

Para setar o valor, use setItem.

```
var horas = '1 hora';

localStorage.setItem('aviso1', horas);
```

Para pegar o valor, use getItem

```
localStorage.getItem('aviso1');
result: '1 hora'
```

---

Editado com um código exemplo:

```
function criarAviso(){
 //pega o horario atual
 var data = new Date().getHours();
 //adiciona mais 3 horas 
 var aviso = data + 3;

 //setou o aviso
 localStorage.setItem('aviso 1', aviso);

}

//pega a hora atual
var dataagora = new Date().getHours();

//pega o aviso
var verificar = localStorage.getItem('aviso 1');

//faz o parse para número
verificar = parseInt(verificar);

//compara o horario
if(verificar <= dataagora){
  //cria a ação para o usuario;
}
```

Pega esse criarAviso e adiciona na ação do botão.

Comment: Eu entendi, mas como posso usar o `localSotrage` em uma página *razor* ? Como eu posso jogar esse valor e pegar e mostrar em uma página html ? Se possível ?

Comment: É possivel renderizar páginas com alguns scripts js?

Comment: Sim sim, sem problemas. Eu preciso guardar esse aviso durante algumas horas. Se com scripts funcionar, ta ótimo !

Comment: Certo, você precisa pegar a data atual do browser pra armazenar no storage, e fazer comparação pra cada atualização do usuário, se o valor que foi armazenado continua sendo maior que o atual. Não existe um worker que trabalha em background no browser para excluir esses dados. Voce pode verificar, caso passe do horário, avisar o usuário e excluir esse aviso

Comment: Poderia colocar em código ?

Comment: Pronto, coloquei o código

Comment: eu fiz um código aqui(vou postar ele) e queria adaptar ele essa parte de expirar. Teria como ?

Comment: Use o window.setTimeout(encerraAvisos, tempo), o tempo é a quantidade de segundos que irá acionar a função encerraAvisos. Cada segundo no tempo, equivale a 1000 ms, então pra você chegar a três horas. Você precisa multiplicar por 60 que são os segundos, mais 60 que são os minutos e mais três que são as horas.
Na função encerraAvisos, você encerra os avisos setados.

Comment: Cara, teria como em código isso também ? Fica meio confuso falando assim. Se puder seria ótimo !